# How to set the layout gravity for a layout, for example a FrameLayout?

Tags: android-layout, gravity

How to set my FrameLayout's layout gravity programatically ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it via `LayoutParams`.

You can't set a Layout's gravity, you can set the gravity of Layout's members like this.

```
View view = new View(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams param = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);
view.setLayoutParams(param);
```